# Is there any sys/queue.h macros for merging two TAILQs

Tags: c, data-structures

I vaguely remember TAILQ_SPLICE() or such function in meritt's gated source code which provided such functionality. Google search did not find any such reference. sys/queue.h in both BSD and linux don't seem to have something like this.

I have a big list and a small list. I want to merge the small list with the bigger one.

```
 struct some_type {
    int some_field;
    TAILQ_ENTRY(some_type) list_next;
}

TAILQ_HEAD(,some_type) big_list;
TAILQ_HEAD(,some_type) small_list1;

TAILQ_SPLICE(&big_list, &small_list, list_next);
```

After this call, the small_list will be empty and all the elements will be moved over to big_list. I would like to use some proven code if available rather than writing it on my own.

Comment: The code snippet below is non trivial. Can you pl. explain the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my testing the following code seems to work.

```
#define TAILQ_SPLICE(head1, head2, headname, field) do {                \
   if (!TAILQ_EMPTY(head2)) {                                           \
       typeof((head1)->tqh_first) first2 = TAILQ_FIRST(head2);          \
       typeof((head1)->tqh_first) last2  = TAILQ_LAST(head2, headname); \
       first2->field.tqe_prev          = (head1)->tqh_last;             \
       if (TAILQ_EMPTY(head1)) {                                        \
           (head1)->tqh_first        = first2;                          \
      } else {                                                          \
           *(head1)->tqh_last    = first2;                              \
      }                                                                 \
      (head1)->tqh_last        = &last2->field.tqe_next;                \
      (head2)->tqh_first = NULL;                                        \
      (head2)->tqh_last = &((head2)->tqh_first);                        \
   }                                                                    \
} while (0);
```

Comment: TAILQ_CONCAT is the one i was looking for